# Value of optional type 'NSNumber' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Tags: swift

In my `UIFontExtension.swift` file, I am getting a Swift compiler error that states...

`Value of optional type 'NSNumber' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?`

This error is pointing to `w!` and `h!` on the lines that I have comments at the end.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIFont {
  func sizeOfString (string: String, maxWidth w: CGFloat?, maxHeight h: CGFloat?) -> CGSize {
    var width = w != nil ? w! : DBL_MAX // Error on this line
    var height = h != nil ? h! : DBL_MAX // And on this line
    var size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    var options = NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin
    var attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: self]
    var nsstring = NSString(string: string)
    return nsstring.boundingRectWithSize(size, options: options, attributes: attributes, context: nil).size
  }
}
```

Is this just a bug?

Comment: My Swift REPL does not produce the error that you've described.

Comment: Interesting. Does it still happen if you don't use the local aliases (use maxWidth and maxHeight in the function instead of w and h)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, wait, I think the problem (maybe) is that the assignment is being interpreted as higher precedence than the comparison. The compiler doesn't know whether the comparison is supposed to be for the entire assignment or just the expression for the assignment. Try adding parentheses:

```
extension UIFont {
  func sizeOfString (string: String, maxWidth w: CGFloat?, maxHeight h: CGFloat?) -> CGSize {
    var width = (w != nil ? w! : DBL_MAX) // Error on this line
    var height = (h != nil ? h! : DBL_MAX) // And on this line
    var size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    var options = NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin
    var attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: self]
    var nsstring = NSString(string: string)
    return nsstring.boundingRectWithSize(size, options: options, attributes: attributes, context: nil).size
  }
}
```

I think that without the parentheses, the assignments are being interpreted as:

```
    (var width = w) != nil ? w! : DBL_MAX // Error on this line
```

Comment: Brilliant! You were right. That's the easiest solution possible.

Comment: @aleclarson: I think it's still a bug, because if it's true the compiler should be inferring the type as `GFloat?` instead of `GFloat`.

Comment: @aleclarson: That is, the type of `width` should have been inferred as `GFloat?`. It looks like they used different code for inferring the type than they used for determining precedence, and in so doing showed why that's a bad idea.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Unlike in the c family of languages, assignment is not an expression in swift, so the right side should always be fully evaluated before the assignment.  I seem to remember some discussion about optional numerics being passed to objective c classes as NSNumbers.  Which jibes more with the error message your getting.

Comment: @David: "That doesn't make sense. Unlike in the c family of languages, assignment is not an expression in swift, so the right side should always be fully evaluated before the assignment."  Yes, that's why it's bug. Read my above comments. The fact that you can move the function out of the extension and it works fine seems proof of that. As for the `NSNumber` thing, `CGFloat` is a typedef for either Float or Double (sort of the equivalent of Swift's `Int`). `Float` and `Double` extend `NSNumber`. So it's reasonable to assume code that specifically handles `CGFloat`s treats them as `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by changing these three lines...

```
func sizeOfString (string: String, maxWidth w: CGFloat?, maxHeight h: CGFloat?) -> CGSize {
  var width = w != nil ? w! : DBL_MAX // Error on this line
  var height = h != nil ? h! : DBL_MAX // And on this line
```

...to this...

```
func sizeOfString (string: String, maxWidth w: CGFloat, maxHeight h: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
  var width = w < 0 ? CGFLOAT_MAX : w
  var height = h < 0 ? CGFLOAT_MAX : h
```

The `CGFloat` parameters are no longer optional. Instead, I convert negative values to `CGFLOAT_MAX` when I don't need a constrained width and/or height.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to bypass this error...

```
var width: CGFloat
if w {
  width = w!
} else {
  width = CGFLOAT_MAX
}

var height: CGFloat
if h {
  height = h!
} else {
  height = CGFLOAT_MAX
}
```

The ternary operator combined with an optional was causing the issue, apparently.